# Static variable in php without objects

Tags: php

I want to define a php variable that can be accessed in all the scripts and is initialized only one time per runtime. This is, like a static variable but with no object. I thought of using $GLOBALS but noticed the variables do not stick between script executions and I would have to instantiate the variable everytime. So how exactly can I accomplish this? Would I need to create an abstract class only to static the variable?

Comment: eDifferent approaches exist, my favorite is to use php's or apaches `auto_prepend_file` feature to have one specific script always executed for each request resulting in php scripts used to serve the request. In that specific file you place any "preparation steps" you need in all scripts: http://php.net/manual/de/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file

Comment: we need more context to adequately answer this question... are you maybe looking for environment variables?

Answer (score 1):

how about using `$_SESSION`? see http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention it should be session widened (truly a GLOBAL variable as in the sense of omnipotence)